# React Navigation turn off animation transition

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation in an react native application and the transition comes up from the bottom of the screen and looks bad. Is there any simple way to just turn off the transition completely. Looking at the documentation and this [post](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1254) this is what I came up with, but it doesn't work.

```
const Navigation = createStackNavigator({
    Home: MainScreen,
    Call: CallScreen,
    Select: SelectScreen,
    Help: HelpScreen
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none',
    navigationOptions: {
      headerVisible: false,
    },
    transitionConfig : () => ({
      transitionSpec: {
          duration: 0,
          easing: Easing.step0,
          timing: Animated.timing,
      },
    }),
  },
);


 export default Navigation;
```